# K8s Fluent-bit output to kafka with k8s-node name

Tags: kubernetes, fluent-bit

as the title description
I want to collect fluent-bit log (with k8s daemonset) then output to kafka
how can I add a column with hostname(not podname)

I had try record_filter add ${HOSTNAME} but it will get pod name not node name

Config Map fluent-bit example